# How to tell Typescript that an item of an optional array cannot be undefined when passed as a function parameter

Tags: typescript

I have a type that is generated by a library, which has an array property that is set to be optional. It looks something like this:

```
type T = {
  node: {
    id: string;
    subfields?: ReadonlyArray<{
      id: string;
    }>;
  };
}
```

I want to pass an item of the `subfields` array to a function in a type-safe way. If the array wasn't optional like in the type above, I could just do this:

```
const myFunc = (param: T["node"]["subfields"][0]) => {
  ...
}
```

But that's not possible when the array is optional; TypeScript gives the following error:

`Property '0' does not exist on type 'readonly { id: string; }[] | undefined'.`

I know, in my code, when I pass an item to the function that it is not undefined because I am checking for it before I call the function. I can't modify the original type object since it's generated by a library, so how can I make the function type-safe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Type type of subfields is:

```
{ id: string }[] | undefined
```

The problem is that it is a union with `undefined`. But you can use [the `Exclude` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#excludetype-excludedunion) to remove possibilities from a union.

For example:

```
type AB = 'a' | 'b'
type A = Exclude<AB, 'b'> // 'a'
```

Also, in general, you should get the type of an array by indexing it with `number`, since that's the type that array's are indexed by.

So putting that together in your case:

```
const myFunc = (param: Exclude<T["node"]["subfields"], undefined>[number]) => {
  //...
}

myFunc({ id: 'def' })
myFunc(undefined) // type error, as expected.
```

Or as @LindaPaiste points out [`NonNullable<T["node"]["subfields"]>` should work nicely](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#nonnullabletype) as well.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.3.2&ssl=15&ssc=46&pln=10&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAKlC8UDeAoKUB2B7AJhAXMmulAJY6EDOwATqRgOYDcx6lArgEYBmpEANjkoB+QgCUIAQxxYM-EAEEaNSSAA8qEiXJVa9ZqygBfAHwt0RlkZQoAxrOpQAtiABi7DLYRQAFGEkqToQAogAetvzseGowANoARNh48QC6CRw8fIKUqQA0UB54vBgQOCaxGOxOnBA0KQCUCCZE6AD0rQB0XSjWKC7unj5IZBRQAORFY8b1fW4etj6FEMWlje1QoJBQtTRYNPmSlNuhkLbApR1AA)

---

However, rather than slicing off pieces of a large and complex type, it's often cleaner to make lots of small types and then assemble them together.

This may not be an option if importing from a library, but if the library's types are implemented in with this strategy, there may be a better type to import for your code.

For example:

```
interface Subfield {
    id: string
}

// Not used in this example, but used in other parts of the application.
type T = {
  node: {
    id: string;
    subfields?: ReadonlyArray<Subfield>;
  };
}

// Now this is dead simple:
const myFunc = (param: Subfield) => {
  //...
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.3.2&ssl=14&ssc=2&pln=12&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMoFcBGNgQDYAmyA3gFDIXLAEBcyAzmFKAOakC+ppYAngA4oAKsgC8JcshAB7AhDplKVWgyasA3BIr0sOfAXoB+OgCUIcAlJB4eAQShQ4PADwZsuQgD4NFdhs6kES0ZkAFseADF0EARRZAAKPjgHELpXXUIASlEPcQoAejyAOmKOLjDI6LjiJToAclkYWuR2DKA)

Comment: Or use NonNullable